# RapidMiner: How to export entire results collection for a process?

Tags: save, rapidminer

I'm aware that I can export a results set to excel and I'm sure it's pretty easy to export individual graphics and confusion tables. And I'm also aware that RapidMiner has a feature where it saves the results from prior versions of a process in a list of result sets within RM. (But only during a particular instance of RM) I'm not asking about any of these things.

If RapidMiner can show me a collection of assets from a prior version of a script ... then it must be storing those assets somewhere (sheets, tables, charts, diagrams, etc). There's got to be a where to either export an entire set or some back door where I can grab the files and .zip them up to share them with entire team and archive them permanently.

My team has created a validation process in RapidMiner that runs all of our individual model processes and evaluation processes in one process that take about 1:20 (hrs) to run. It creates a collection of 12-20 assets (lift-charts, decision trees, neural net diagrams, confusion tables, etc.

How can I bundle up this set and save it off? I'm hoping someone can give me a better method than exporting each one individually.

Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One of the nice things about RapidMiner is extensions.

You could check this [extension](https://marketplace.rapidminer.com/UpdateServer/faces/product_details.xhtml?productId=rmx_adv_reporting) out. A demo version is available as well.

A [blog](https://oldworldcomputing.com/en/advanced-reporting-extension-an-introduction/) from the company which worked on the **Advanced Reporting** extension, describes that you could use it to write your report into Excel sheets and fully customize it.